# Simulate an Azure Service Bus delivery failure

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Is there any way to simulate an Azure Service Bus message delivery failure?

I have a Receiver application written in .NET, I need to test and write failover methods for message delivery. I'm struggling to find a way to simulate a delivery failure.

Comment: You ca have a look at [azure chaos studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/chaos-studio/). Not sure if it supports servicebus tho

Comment: It would be helpful to understand which SDK package you're using and a bit more for what a "delivery failure" means in this context.